# String permutaion

Tags: java, permutation

I have found the following Java code. It counts all the permutations of a string. However, I can't understand what it does inside the for loop of the permutation method. More specifically I can't understand the purpose of the rem string and the recursive call.

Is there any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

```
void permutaion(String str){
    permutaion(str,"");
}

void permutaion(String str, String prefix){
    if(str.length() == 0){
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else{
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
            String rem = str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1);
            permutaion(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need to do is draw a picture with an example of 'abc'.  It should read left to right when your done making the tree.

Comment: `rem` == "remainder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is this: to get the permutations of a given *N*-character string you:

1. Take the first letter of the original string and append to it all the permutations of the remaining *N* - 1 characters;
2. Take the first two letters of the original string and append to them all the permutations of the remaining *N* - 2 characters;
3. Take the first three letters of the original string and append to them all the permutations of the remaining *N* - 3 characters ...

Answer (score 0):

You should run this code by hand on paper to see it's magic and understand it :)
The recursive on `permutation` function is for permutation input string, and the for loop is for all possible case. The `prefix` is the permutation of the input string when a recursive finish.